# MySQL - Counting multiple parameters from the same subquery

Tags: mysql, innodb, subquery, count

I have a very large MySQL (~10M rows) database, currently using the InnoDB engine, which stores log events. I am working on a front-end that allows searching through this log database, and one of the features of this front-end is the ability to filter by certain values of the event. For the visual, the filter is a select-multiple element that lists both the possible values and the number of events currently matching that value:

[image]

However the queries I'm using to count these values are causing a significant performance hit. Part of the issue I'm having is I currently have 7 different parameters I allow filtering on, as well as more general filters (e.g. time window), so for each of these 7 parameters I'm running something like:

`SELECT parameter1, count(parameter1) FROM table WHERE log_time > 'Some Date' AND parameter2 = 'Something' AND parameter3 = ... GROUP BY parameter1`

...where parameter 2, 3, etc. are other conditions that have already been set. So I'm applying the same where condition to all 7 count queries, which seems redundant to me. I know I can reformat this to use a subquery instead of the where condition, but is it possible to then count all 7 filters off the same subquery?

Another idea I had was to create a temporary table which gets populated with the results of the subquery, and is then interrogated for the 7 filter counts. In testing this did overall save some time, but seems like overkill to me (especially from a disk IOP perspective).

I also tried switching the table to MyISAM, since `count()` operations are supposed to be faster there, but didn't notice a significant difference in query time. I'm guessing this is because I'm using where conditions that force full table scans anyway.

== Edit 1 ==

Here is the table structure of one of my test tables (condensed version of the actual table, only including values that are filtered on):

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `temp_3` (
  `client` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_type` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `result_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_country_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_organization` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_creation_time` (`creation_time`),
  KEY `idx_client` (`client`),
  KEY `idx_record_type` (`record_type`),
  KEY `idx_operation` (`operation`),
  KEY `idx_result_status` (`result_status`),
  KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `idx_client_ip` (`client_ip`),
  KEY `idx_source_country_code` (`source_country_code`),
  KEY `idx_source_organization` (`source_organization`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I was testing with and without index on all the counted values, they help but not massively (maybe 20-30% faster with indexes). I have not tried any composite indexes yet.

Comment: in mysqö8 you have ctes, so you could first select alle the data and use the result to count, you stoill need a combined index on all parameters.

Comment: 1. Post DDL of the table or provide the approximate row size in bytes.  2. How often is the table updated?

Comment: @bbaird: 1. Edited to include table structure 2. Constantly, during peak work hours the table averages ~1.5-2k new events per minute.

Comment: @nbk CTEs may work here, I'm currently looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196808/use-one-cte-many-times) post for how to reuse the same CTE for all 7 count queries

Comment: the link is for sql server but it works in mysql too, still don't forget to make a combined index

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'm a bit confused on the combined index here (read: novice in that area). I saw somewhere that mysql supports index joins where the optimizer can use multiple indexes in one query, are the combined indexes still significantly better? Also, with 7 filter possibilities, wouldn't that give me 7! possible combined index combinations? How do I go about figuring out which combinations I actually need?

Comment: Start with [how mysql uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) and [index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql). Do you want `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(param)` look up the difference if `param` is `NULL`. MyISAM counts are only fast on a full table. Select common param (7! indexes is too much) use enough to restrict the dataset significantly and to limit the dataset searched. If its always a time window `creation_time` will come first in the index. Use `EXPLAIN {query}` on some sample sets to see how useful it is.